# Creating lookup field in MS Access - better to have one or many source tables?

Tags: ms-access

I'm creating a database to track our participants in Access 2010.

Main data is stored in a table called ParticipantMaster.

I have a few fields in ParticipantMaster that I want to assign lookup values to.

School (MLK High, Central High, Northeast High...)

Interests (Visual Arts, Drama, Sports, Literature....)

Color (Red, Blue, Green...)

I could create a table School, another table Interests, another table Color,  and then have the source for each one to be `SELECT Color.ColorName FROM Color` and then `SELECT School.SchoolName FROM School` and then `SELECT Interests.InterestPicker from Interest`.... this is how I usually do things.

But then I wondered if instead of three separate tables, I could have one table called ParticipantData with fields called School, Interests, Color... and then have my lookup queries be `SELECT ParticipantData.School from ParticipantData`, and `SELECT ParticipantData.Interests FROM ParticipantData`, and `SELECT ParticipantData.Color FROM ParticipantData`

Are there advantages/disadvantages to one way or the other?

Comment: Does ParticipantData store the school, color, and interests for a Participant or would is store the choices of school, color, and interests?

Comment: just the choices.  There's another table called ParticipantMaster where all that is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lookup table you described was a bit unique. Most people wouldn't suggest you do this.

```
    ParticipantData
 +-----------------------+
 | School    (text)      |
 | Color     (text)      |
 | Interests (text)      |
 +-----------------------+
```

The one below makes a bit more sense

```
    ParticipantData
 +-----------------------+
 | ID (AutoNumber)       |
 |-----------------------|
 | LookupType (number)   |
 | LookupValue (text)    |
 +-----------------------+
```

the major downsides to having a single table like this are

1. Its really hard to make the Foreign Key constraints perfect. e.g. You want to limit ParicipantMaster.Color to just IDs that correspond to the LookupType color but the best you can do is limits it to IDs that are in the Participant Data table.
2. It becomes painful if you want to add attributes to just one LookupType. For example you want to add SchoolDistrict to the LookupType of school you have a bunch of undesirable choices. (A. Allow schoolDistrict to be an attibute of color. B. Rip out the School from the lookup table and fix all your code, C. Add a table that links to participant table)

Comment: +1 I use a lookup table like this as well. You're right about the problem with adding attributes to *one* lookup type. I don't do this - if a lookup type becomes more complex than the "default" number of fields supported by the generic lookup table, I move the lookup type to its own table. But the lookup table helps me avoid creating lots of single, three column, three row tables for the 90% of lookup types that have nothing but a number and a value.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the second method and it wasn't too bad, but in the end, I wished I had gone with the first method. It is a lot easier to control and to add new items.

I hope you are not intending to have look-ups in your tables.

Comment: Thanks --- I figured the second way would work but was wondering what specific advantages/disadvantages there might be to one way or the other.  And no...  the lookups will be in the forms.  I've learned not to put them in tables.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually combined both approaches.  I'll warn you now this may be long-winded and might come across as overkill.  However, I've found this to be a good generic solution that **scales really well**.

The approach consists of a total of four tables:

```
PDLists (local to the front-end)
--------
K*PDListID        Long          
 *PDListName      Text (50)     
  CodeLen         Long          
 *UserCanEdit     Boolean [False]             
 *HasActiveCheck  Boolean [False]             

PDChoices (linked to the back-end)
---------
K*PDChoiceID  Long AUTONUMBER             
 *PDListID    Long          
  PDCode      Text (10)     
 *PDDesc      Text (255)    
 *Seq         Long          
 *IsActive    Boolean [True]

PDChoicesLocked (local to the front-end)
---------------
K*PDChoiceID  Long AUTONUMBER             
 *PDListID    Long          
  PDCode      Text (10)     
 *PDDesc      Text (255)    
 *Seq         Long          
 *IsActive    Boolean [True]              

PDFields (local to the front-end)
--------
K*PDListID    Long          
K*TblName     Text (50)     Used to enforce referential integrity for fields that use code:description pair & to restrict length of text entry
K*FldName     Text (50)     Used to enforce referential integrity for fields that use code:description pair & to restrict length of text entry
```

LEGEND: `K`: Primary Key; `*`: Required Field; `[Foo]`: Default Value

### PDLists

The first table has an entry for each lookup table.  The `CodeLen` (code length) field is used for lookups where you want to store a meaningful abbreviation.  For example, you would set `CodeLen = 1` for a lookup like: `N: North; E: East; S: South; W: West`.

If `UserCanEdit` is True, then the pulldown choices are stored in the back-end table PDChoices.  Otherwise, they are stored in the local table PDChoicesLocked.

I have a helper function that generates the SQL statement to use in combo boxes.  I pass it the PDListID and it checks the CodeLen and UserCanEdit fields to create an appropriate SELECT statement.  The helper function simply prints this to the immediate window and I copy and paste it where I need it.

```
PDListID   PDListName            CodeLen   UserCanEdit   HasActiveCheck
   1       Cardinal Directions      1          True          False
```

### PDChoices/PDChoicesLocked

The only difference between these two tables is where they are located (explained above).  I could have combined both tables into one on the backend, but having the locked table local means that I can alter this table during development and can guarantee its contents even if I deploy my program to different clients.

The `Seq` (sequence) field is used to allow custom sorting of the choices.  And the `IsActive` field allows hiding of choices in the dropdown without losing referential integrity if those lookups are currently in use.

```
PDChoiceID    PDListID    PDCode    PDDesc    Seq    IsActive
    1             1         N       North      1        True
    2             1         E       East       3        True
    3             1         S       South      2        True
    4             1         W       West       4        True
```

### PDFields

This table exists to enforce referential integrity.  This cannot actually be accomplished at the database level, so it gets enforced in the form that users can use to make changes to the pulldown choices.

```
PDListID   TblName           FieldName
   1       StreetAddresses   CardinalDirection
   1       Locations         CompassPoint
```

### Pulldowns Form

When users double-click on a combo box with user-editable choices (ie, `UserCanEdit=True`) then a Pulldown form is loaded.  The form caption is set to `PDListName`.  If `CodeLen` is not null then a textbox for the lookup code is made visible.  If `HasActiveCheck=True` then a checkbox is shown that allows the user to toggle the Active status of individual pull-down choices.

I have a custom function that limits the number of characters that can be input into the `PDCode` field based on the `CodeLen`.  However, if `CodeLen` is null, then I check to see if I need to limit the length of the `PDDesc` field.  For example, if the field type of a field is Long, then I assume I am saving the PDChoiceID in the field and I don't limit the length of `PDDesc`.  But if the referenced field is a Text/Varchar field then I get the length of that field and limit the length of `PDDesc` accordingly.

When the Pulldowns form is closed, I requery the combo box the user double-clicked so that they have immediate access to any new options they added.

### Summary

This approach has one major disadvantage:  it is a lot of work to get it all set up initially.  However, a lot of that work is in providing the user editable table in the back-end and a form to allow the user to update those choices.  If you stick to just the three local tables you gain scalability and flexibility without a ton of work.

**Pros**:

- it is **flexible**; the values can be stored in your main table multiple ways

  - by PDChoiceID
  - by PDCode
  - by PDDesc
- it is **scalable**; once the initial setup is done, adding new lookups is a breeze
- it is **powerful**;

  - choices can be removed from the pulldown without being deleted by setting `IsActive=False`
  - the sort order of the items is fully customizable
  - you can provide an interface to let users make changes to the list without sacrificing referential integrity

**Cons**:

- it is more work to set up initially than the two options you presented
- you cannot enforce referential integrity at the database layer; I don't see this as a major Con because if you are careful you can still enforce referential integrity at the application layer

One last note.  I realize that Access 2007 introduced a feature to allow users to add items to a combo box.  From a developer's standpoint that feature is useless because the changes are stored in the front-end (and it provides no referential integrity).  My approach stores those changes in the back-end (where they belong) and I continue to use it going forward despite Access 2007's new feature.