# Can combobox be built dynamically on load with a row value from a table?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I've a large number of ComboBox controls in my form, and originally had all the values in a table for each control, but this gave me over a 100 tables - too many, so I've been told to create one table to hold all the ComboBox values, with a column for the control name and a column for the values, then use the form's load event to dynamically fill all the ComboBoxs with the values. Problem is I can't see how to do this. Using AddItem I'd have to have an AddItem line for every value in every ComboBox in VBA, which I think defeats the purpose. I've tried to define a string to hold the values as a list, and then set the control's RowSourceType to Value List and RowSource to the string, and VBA doesn't like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A hundred look-up combos is not a major problem. A single table with all the look-up information is likely to become a problem.

You can set the row source of the combo in a relevant event, say Load,  to:

```
SELECT ValueField FROM ComboTable 
WHERE ComboName = 'MyCombo'
```

See also: [Creating lookup field in MS Access - better to have one or many source tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347412/creating-lookup-field-in-ms-access-better-to-have-one-or-many-source-tables)